# Self Union All in Tableau Public for Sankey Diagram

Tags: data, visualization, sql, tableau

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HwCzlA9hI4) 2017 YouTube tutorial from which I hope to learn [Sankey diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram).

At [2:28](https://youtu.be/1HwCzlA9hI4?list=PLE50-dh6JzC450Hn6EjPM238yZUPs-RQ1&t=148), he instructs us to select `Convert to Custom SQL`, after having opened the [spreadsheet](https://sds-platform-private.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/P18-African-Mobile-Data.zip) in legacy mode - in order to do a Union All of `SalesData` (on itself).

**Problems:**

- `Legacy mode` was not an option when opening
- `Convert to Custom SQL` isn't in any of the options
- All other [Union options](https://help.tableau.com/v2019.2/public/desktop/en-us/union.htm) don't seem to allow for a `Union All`

**Main Question:**

- How do I do a 'self' Union All on a table in Tableau Public?

**Contextual Questions:**

- Is it that the Tableau UI has changed so much since 2017?
- or, is this option not even available in Tableau Public?
- or, is this just a bad direction for Sankey diagrams in the first-place?